# How to use Hero web part in publishing template SharePoint online 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365

**Goal**:
I want to add a Hero part (or something similar which allows to present links as tiles/pictures with grid) to a page on a site which has template 'publishing'.

**Problem**:
It seems like the Hero web part is not available with this template, and summary links do not solve the problem.

**What I've already done**:
- I know it is not possible to add promoted links in sharepoint 365
- Quick links are very difficult (if possible at all) to use in my desired way
- I tried using sharepoint designer to copy code from aspx file of a page with hero web part, but SPD doesn't show code for my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoted links are certainly supported on classic sites in O365. Can you not add the app?

As an alternative, you can add a modern page to a publishing site. Of course, this would be changing out all the web parts, not just the one, but it would accomplish this specific goal. You may have to turn on the site pages feature first, as documented [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Modern-Pages-in-Existing-Publishing-Sites/td-p/83889).

Comment: To enable Site Pages:    
    
Activate Site Settings > Manage site features > Site Pages > Activate    
    
Add modern pages by going to Site Contents > Site Pages > New > Site Page    
(It might take some time for the new setting to kick in)    
    
(Taken from the link provided by Mike2500)      
    
Works for me! Thank you for your help